# How to recover idea.properties file

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have android studio 1.4.1 and I erroneously overwrote the idea.properties file, now I want to recover it.

how can I find it

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file inside Android Studio and look for Local History. If it happened recently there is a good chance to find you lost data there.

Comment: the idea.properties file is not shown in android studio project explorer